# Connection closed when sleeping long durations in between HttpClient requests

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I'm using Apache HttpComponents and specifically HttpClient for the first time. I have a fairly basic use case. I'm polling some third party server every N seconds (in this case their API is expecting a POST).

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().
    setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).build();
```

Then I'm executing some POST requests in a loop... using:

```
while (!someCondition) {
    HttpPost httpPost = ...
    httpclient.execute(httpPost)
    Thread.sleep(SOME_TIME)
}
```

I noticed if I sleep for some longer duration, like 3 minutes, then I don't get a response back from the server and the connection dies consistently every time:

```
DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] http-outgoing-1 << "end of stream"
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-1: Close connection
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-1: Shutdown connection
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Connection discarded
DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-1: Close connection
```

I don't believe it's the server. I'm probably not using HttpComponents properly or I have it misconfigured. If I set it to a shorter duration like 1 minute, it works OK (I did notice it died after running ~15 minutes - so that's fifteen one minute intervals).

To send the request, I wrapped it in some Java 8 lambdas and utilize try with resources, but I don't think this matters:

```
private <R> R sendRequest(HttpUriRequest request, Function<String, R> func) {
    try {
        try (CloseableHttpResponse resp = this.httpclient.execute(request)) {
            HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();

            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            R result = null;
            if (func != null) {
                result = func.apply(responseString);
            }

            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            return result;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Error sending request: " + request, e);
    }
}
```

The actual exception is:

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: myserver.com:80 failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
```

Comment: Is the last exception you showed really the root cause of the exception? Nothing from Java's network layer (IOException?)

Comment: I believe so. It's been currently running for about 25 minutes (at ~30 second sleep duration) so I don't want to kill it now. But I will follow up on it.

Comment: Is there a firewall between your client and the http server?

Comment: If you are seeing 'http-outgoing-1 << "end of stream"' in the log that basically means the connection was closed by the opposite endpoint.

Comment: @oleg I understand that's what appears to be happening. I don't understand why if I create an HttpClient instance, send one request, wait 3 minutes, and send another request, it fails every time. But if I instead sleep for ~30 seconds, it can run fine for almost 2 hours. Should I be creating a new HttpClient instance every time I want to send a request instead? I assumed I can have one instance and it manages pooling connections, handling retries, etc. for me (since I'm using those default configs).

Comment: I've changed my code so that the bootstrap code to send some initial requests uses one HttpClient instance. That instance is closed and then it enters the long-pull "loop" method. In the loop method, I create a new HttpClient instance, send a few POSTs, gracefully close, wait 3 minutes and repeat and it appears to be working fine. Perhaps my misunderstanding is assuming HttpClient is analogous to my web browser and it does not matter how long I wait in between requests (and if any reused internal connections die I expected it to create new ones!).

Comment: @nogridbag What version of HttpClient are using? In any case instead of discarding HttpClient instance you should rather be evicting all persistent connections from the pool. Once I know the version you are using I can give you a more detailed answer

Comment: Thanks - httpcomponents 4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very common and natural for HTTP servers to close out persistent connections that have been idle over a maximum period of inactivity in order to conserve resources. In your particular case if the client generates a request every 30 seconds the server keeps the connection alive, whereas if the connection stays idle longer it gets eventually closed on the server side (and becomes half-closed or 'stale' on the client side). Next time the client leases the connection from the pool and attempts to use it to execute a request, execution fails with an I/O exception. This is perfectly normal and can be expected. HttpClient tries to mitigate the problem by doing so-called stale connection check in order to find out whether or not the connection has been closed by the opposite endpoint or has become invalid otherwise. The 'stale' checks are relatively expensive and should be used sparingly. HttpClient as of version 4.4 seeks to improve performance out of the box by performing the check selectively. There was a defect in version 4.4 which basically disabled connection validation altogether. Please upgrade to version 4.4.1 and the problem should go away.

Having said all that I still think that the best course of action in your case is to evict all persistent connections from the connection pool prior to long periods of inactivity by using `HttpClientConnectionManager#closeIdleConnections`

Comment: Thanks!  In my particular case, I don't know if there's any particular downside to closing the HttpClient, letting it get GC'ed, and creating a new  instance. Any performance gains by keeping the same HttpClient instance are negligible as I'm sleeping on the order of minutes in between requests. Is there any other reason besides performance to hold onto a single HttpClient instance? Thanks again.

Comment: Keeping conversation state: cookies, auth cache, user token, etc

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (NoHttpResponseException: myserver:port failed to respond) with all GET requests working and all POST and PUT requests failing. It was due to the HTTP client by default compressing the request body and the server not expecting it compressed and treating the request as with empty body.

These were the logs on the server side:

```
[2017-03-01 11:32:51,074][WARN ][http.netty][host-elasticsearch] Caught exception while handling client http traffic, closing connection [details]
TransportException[Support for compressed content is disabled. You can enable it with http.compression=true]

[2017-03-01 11:32:51,074][WARN ][http.netty] [host-elasticsearch] Caught exception while handling client http traffic, closing connection [details]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: received HttpChunk without HttpMessage
```

I was using jerseyClient (Dropwizard) and solved the problem simply setting in the yaml config:

```
jersey-client:
  gzipEnabled: false
```

Hope this helps someone.